# Does improvement in human capital reduces regional disparity?

Tags: human-capital

I am an undergraduate student and I am finding out if this could be a good thesis topic since I haven't encountered any text regarding this also when I found one related to this it is on the other way around like how does income affect difference on human capital between regions.

Sub-question: Will increase in human capital create convergence between regions?

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by improvement in human resources? Please elaborate.

Comment: for e.g. if that region improve when it comes to literacy or maybe on their human development in general? do you think that would help periphery regions to catch up from other regions and lessen their disparity? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean "human capital" instead of "human resources"? If yes, please change and elaborate your answer

Comment: I already changed it. Thank you